# Entity Framework 4.0 Code-First Dynamic Query

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I would like to query a table based on a list of `KeyValuePair`. With a Model-First approach, I could do the following:

```
var context = new DataContext();
var whereClause = new StringBuilder();
var objectParameters = new List<ObjectParameter>();

foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in queryParameters)
{
    if (whereClause.Length > 0)
        whereClause.Append(" AND ");
    whereClause.Append(string.Format("it.[{0}] = @{0}", pair.Key));
    parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter(pair.Key, pair.Value));
}

var result = context.Nodes.Where(whereClause.ToString(), parameters.ToArray());
```

Now I'm using a Code-First approach and [this Where method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338811.aspx) is not available anymore. Fortunately, I saw an article somewhere (I can't remember anymore) which suggested that I could convert the `DbContext` to a `IObjectContextAdapter` then call `CreateQuery` like this:

```
var result = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context)
                .ObjectContext.CreateQuery<Node>(whereClause.ToString(), parameters.ToArray());
```

Unfortunately, this throws an error:

**'{ColumnName}' could not be resolved in the current scope or context. Make sure that all referenced variables are in scope, that required schemas are loaded, and that namespaces are referenced correctly.**

Where **{ColumnName}** is the column specified in the `whereClause`.

Any ideas how I can dynamically query a `DbSet` given a list of key/value pairs? All help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We use System.Linq.Dynamic for this. It's an add-on, but worth it IMHO. Not really the question you're asking, but it's a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks again Craig!! I really liked your approach and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your very first problem is that in the first example you are using `Where` on the entity set but in the second example you are using `CreateQuery` so you must pass full ESQL query and not only where clause! Try something like:

```
...
.CreateQuery<Node>("SELECT VALUE it FROM ContextName.Nodes AS it WHERE " + yourWhere)
```

The most problematic is full entity set name in `FROM` part. I think it is defined as name of the context class and name of the `DbSet` exposed on the context. Another way to do it is creating `ObjectSet`:

```
...
.ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<Node>().Where(yourWhere)
```

Comment: +1 for being generally right, but use params or sanitize if the "where" involves user data.

Comment: @Craig: I agree. I just made the example too slovenly. Where clause should not be build with string concatenation.

Comment: When I try the second suggestion, I get an error: **DbContext does not contain a definition of 'CreateObjectSet' and no extension method....**

Comment: That is not method of `DbSet` but the method of `ObjectContext`. You must convert `DbContext` to `ObjectContext` as you did before and then you can call this method.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help. I must also mention that I tried the suggestion by @Craig and it works too. I prefer that approach however, this is the answer to my question.