# How to dynamically get a generic C# object reference

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

With many efforts in my side, i get the following code executing:

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance("Assemblyname", "TypeName").Unwrap();
//Code to fill instance using reflection
DbContext.Set(instance.GetType()).Add(instance);
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

now i want to achieve something like following code:

```
var u = DbContext.Users;
var z = from y in u
where y.Email =="some email"
select y;
```

but i want get `u` Dynamically, i need something first piece of code to reference existent entity inside `DbContext`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use [ESQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6298081/298573)
- Or try the [LINQ Dynamic Query Library](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/7d29f8d8-875e-47c5-adb2-eb8756be36c1/#cc1ce970-02da-4b9e-8067-c37a33461c8d)

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for

`DbContext.Set(typeof(User))`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679544(v=vs.103).aspx

There is a generic version as well:

`DbContext.Set<User>()`

Comment: yes i need generic version, but my problem is that it must be reference dynamically, like first piece of code

Comment: the exact problem is that one time i need user, another time another type